# What is the resistance of a land line telephone

Tags: voltage

can some one tell me what size resistor would i need to place across a telephone line in order to hold the line open at 6 volts off hook voltage? On hook there is 48 volts, off hook drops down to about 6 volts, i am replacing a standard telephone with a load resistor for a project I am building. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used audio transformer P/N 42TM016-RC (from mouser) with 470 ohm resistor in series on the side connected to the phone line to get off hook voltage of approximately 6V. The resistance of the transformer's primary side is 65 ohms. This would give equivalent resistance of about 545 ohms. You can play with the resistor value little bit to adjust the off hook voltage. This combination worked great for audio and sending/receiving DTMF signals.

Answer (score 1):

A dc resistance less than 200 ohms is required. This will create voltages from 3 to maybe 9V. If you want to transmit/receive audio, an ac impedance of 600 ohms is recomended.

The on-hook dc impedance should be more than 5 Mohms to 100V and 30 kohms to 200V.

Notice that the standards differs between countries.

Also if your equipment could be connected to a fax machine or other non-standard port, it is more likely to work with lower voltages.

Don't forget lightning protection, if you connect to real phone lines. Very important in countries where phone lines are above ground.